# Can I make a collapse/expandable area?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Is it possible to make a collapse/expandable section in a question ?

Comment: Spoilers? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13736/947379

Comment: Maybe. I don't want my long equations to take a lot of space for people who don't need to see them. not sure if spoilers work this way

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13259/888233)?

Comment: Thanks @soupless for the link. It is really cool.

Comment: A related feature request: [Please add the ability to fold blocks of code in questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5199). It is marked ([meta-tag:status-declined]).